Discord Views: Do views leave memory when message is deleted?
I'm making updates to my bot and want to use views and buttons for a better user experience. I'm a bit confused on how they are removed, however. I thought they would be gone once the message that displayed them was deleted, but I'm not so sure. I'm struggling to find a method to even check if they are still present. The last thing I want is for them to stay in memory forever and bog down my server over time.
Here are some simple code snippets with comments to explain
My bot's on_ready event:
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    logging.info('-------------------------------')
    logging.info('Starting the DatabaseManager...')
    await bot.db_manager.start()
    logging.info('DatabaseManager is ready')
    logging.info('Setting up the database...')
    await setup_database(bot)
    logging.info('Database is ready')
    logging.info(
        f'Bot version {__version__} is ready'
    )
    logging.info('-------------------------------')
    # The below was added to keep created buttons persistent
    # It appears to NOT work without it; if the bot disconnects
    # or reboots they will not work until I add this code back in
    view = MyView()
    bot.add_view(view)
    # this just prints out the children of the view. Its intent
    # was to determine if the button was removed when the message
    # was deleted, but since the view includes the button well...
    # it's just not helpful lol
    for component in view.children:
        print(type(component), component.label, component.custom_id)

A simple cog that creates a view in another channel with a button:
class QuestCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
    @quest.subcommand(
        description='Creates a joinable party queue for 2-5 users',
    )
    async def party_queue(
        self,
        interaction: Interaction,
    ):
        queue_channel = await self.bot.get_channel(123456789)
        # I make an instance of the view here because it's the only way I
        # could make it work. Somehow the addition of an instance of this view
        # to the bot makes it persistent. I have no idea how that works, but it does.
        # the question is, when I delete the below queue_message, what happens to
        # the instance of the view and whatever is added to it? Stays in memory forever
        # or does Nextcord have some sort of auto collector that dumps it since the
        # message is gone?
        view = MyView()
        queue_message = await queue_channel.send(
            "This is a queue.\n"
            f"The quests bill begin <t:{start_time}:R>\n\n", view=view
        )
        await interaction.response.send_message(
            f"TBD ({queue_message.id})"
        )

And here is the view:
class MyView(View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.add_item(MyButton())

class MyButton(Button):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(label="Click Me", style=ButtonStyle.primary, custom_id="my_button")

    async def callback(self, interaction: Interaction):
        try:
            message_id = interaction.message.id
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"Button clicked! Message ID: {message_id}", ephemeral=True)
        except nextcord.errors.NotFound:
            logging.error(
                'You have joined the queue! Message ID: '
                f'{interaction.message.id}'
            )
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")

I've tried to cut things down to the root of the issue, rather than blob of code that's irrelevant to the question. Thanks to anyone who can help me understand, or at least test to ensure I won't create a bloated up memory on my server.
